# Combining fold and filter

Tags: ocaml

So I'm writing a combining function for fold that will make it perform filtering.

```
let filter_combine (pred: 'a -> bool) : a' list -> 'a list -> 'a list =
fun (x: 'a) (y: 'a list) -> x :: (filter pred y)
```

I am not having any compilation issues, but one out of my two test cases is failing. What is wrong with my implementation?

This is the test case that fails...

```
[-1; 1] = fold (filter_combine (fun (x: int) -> (abs x) mod 2 <> 0)) [] [-2; -1; 0; 1; 2]
```

This is the one that works...

```
[-2; 2] = fold (filter_combine (fun (x: int) -> (abs x) > 1)) [] [-2; -1; 0; 1; 2]
```

Comment: `filter_combine` is ill-typed, or `filter` is not `List.filter`.

Comment: you should provide the signatures of `fold` and `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding this question. I think what you're saying is that you want to write a function that takes a predicate and returns a function suitable for use with a fold so that the result will filter according to the predicate.

Some problems with the question:

- There's no built-in OCaml function named `fold`.
- If you're supposed to implement filtering, it seems fairly weird to use `filter` in your implementation.

If I assume you're using `fold_right`, then it seems to me you'd want to return a function of type `a -> a list -> a list`. It wants to look at one thing to decide what to do, not at a whole list of things. Since you say you're not getting compilation errors, this suggests that your function named `fold` doesn't work as I would expect. It might help if you showed how `fold` actually works.